# audio_common not catkinized?

Tags: ros, catkin, audio-common

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying to migrate to catkin.
I have packages that depend on things in audio_common.
Is audio_common going to be migrated or deprecated?
Are there any good alternatives?

Any information would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Ryan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62648/audio_common-not-catkinized?/) by [dellanar04](https://answers.ros.org/users/4884/dellanar04/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-05-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-13**:
Not an official answer, but I expect it will be maintained and migrated. There are probably lots of users.

**Comment by [dellanar04](https://answers.ros.org/users/4884/dellanar04/) on 2013-05-13**:
That's fine. I can get along without it until Hydro. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@ahendrix recently catkinized `audio_common` for Hydro, I think he can comment on it when he gets back from Germany.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-05-20**:
Confirmed; audio_common has been migrated to catkin for Hydro.